# Can Germans distinguish “iSelf” from “iShelf” by pronunciation?

Tags: pronunciation, phonetics

Would German-speaking people notice the difference of pronunciation between  *iShelf* and *iSelf?*

Comment: Of course they will. Why do you think they wouldn't?

Comment: This is related to trademark law. The possibility of confusion between two brands is an important factor when a trademark application is analysed.

Comment: @VladLego: Given that, [from the point of view of the owner of the "Gelbe Seiten" ("yellow pages") brand, something called "Schwarze Seiten" ("black pages") was too close to be clearly distinguishable](http://www.heise.de/newsticker/meldung/Telekom-erhebt-Anspruch-auf-schwarze-Seiten-51821.html), I wouldn't bet that despite hearing a difference, that alone is sufficient to establish that there is no possibility of confusion.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not about German.

Comment: @c.p.: Take a look at the answers to see what this has to do with the German language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, they would.

*iShelf* is pronounced [aɪʃɛlf] and *iSelf* is pronounced [aɪsɛlf]. The differing sounds [ʃ] and [s] are both part of the German phoneme repertoire and distinguishing them is essential to understand the German language. For example, the German words *Busch* ([bʊʃ]) and *Bus* ([bʊs]) or *Sex* ([sɛks]) and *Schecks* ([ʃɛks]) only differ by that sound. Thus German ears are trained to that difference and will notice it.

By contrast, Germans usually have problems in recognising the difference between *man* ([mæn]) and *men* ([mɛn]), as [æ] is not part of the German phoneme repertoire.

Comment: Does their language need to comprise a phoneme for them to recognize such a difference? If one says *mään* (“man”) and *menn* (“men”), it’s quite distinguishable. More than, say, [“jews” and “juice”](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zpa-CMeqKFo).

Comment: @dakab: *Does their language need to comprise a phoneme for them to recognize such a difference?* – If the phonemes are close, it certainly helps and it’s the only reason I could think of why distinguishing the two could fail at all. Germans certainly have no trouble in distinguishing [æ] from [þ] (one of the English *th* sounds), though both are not German phonemes. — *If one says* mään *(“man”) and* menn *(“men”), it’s quite distinguishable.* – Yes, but that would be [mɛːn] vs. [mɛn]. The former has little to do with actual English pronunciation.

Comment: _Busch:Bus_ is not an appropriate minimal pair here, because whether phonemes are distinguished also depends on their syllabic position. In final/coda position, German has /-ʃ/ and /-s/ indeed (and no /-z/), but in initial/onset position it natively only has /ʃ-/ and /z-/ (no /s-/). Originally, initial /s-/ can be a dialectal allophone (e.g. /staɪn/ in Hamburg), but there are loan words now to make minimal pairs or even triples (in Standard German at least), e.g. _Sex:sechs:Schecks_ (plus _Checks_ /tʃ-/, _Jacks_ /(d)ʒ-/, _Specks, steck’s, schmeck’s, schleck’s_ as required – _Swags_?).

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: By *mään*, I meant `/mæn/`, the common English pronunciation of “man”, which certainly *has* sth. to do with English. I doubt that “man” and “men”—properly vocalized—are difficult for Germans to differentiate.

Comment: @Crissov: I do not think it matters that much, as this is not about what is a phonemic difference in German but what sounds German ears can distinguish. If you are trained to distinguish two sounds in final position, you should also be able to distinguish them in initial position. Nontheless, I added the *Sex–Schecks* example – thanks for that.

Comment: @dakab: *I doubt that “man” and “men”—properly vocalized—are difficult for Germans to differentiate.* – Well, I have no statistics on this, but I have heard German native speakers claim that *man* and *men* do not differ in pronunciation at least three times in my life.

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely. [s] and [ʃ] represent different phonemes in German (just as in English), so speakers of German will distinguish them.